# Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. GCC error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, gcc, rubygems

I upgraded rails to 4.2.0 and ruby to 2.2.1. First I upgraded rails and everything was fine. When I upgraded the ruby version to 2.2.1 and ran `bundle install`, it gives me the following error.

```
 Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/ps032791/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20150406-64754-18zessv.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile
Compiling v8 for x64
Using python 2.7.5
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Unable to find a compiler officially supported by v8.
It is recommended to use GCC v4.4 or higher
Using compiler: g++
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Unable to find a compiler officially supported by v8.
It is recommended to use GCC v4.4 or higher
../src/cached-powers.cc:136:18: error: unused variable 'kCachedPowersLength' [-Werror,-Wunused-const-variable]
static const int kCachedPowersLength = ARRAY_SIZE(kCachedPowers);
                 ^
1 error generated.
make[1]: *** [/Users/ps032791/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@record/gems/libv8-3.11.8.17/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/cached-powers.o] Error 1
make: *** [x64.release] Error 2
/Users/ps032791/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@record/gems/libv8-3.11.8.17/ext/libv8/location.rb:36:in `block in verify_installation!': libv8 did not install properly, expected binary v8 archive '/Users/ps032791/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@record/gems/libv8-3.11.8.17/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/tools/gyp/libv8_base.a'to exist, but it was not found (Libv8::Location::Vendor::ArchiveNotFound)
    from /Users/ps032791/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@record/gems/libv8-3.11.8.17/ext/libv8/location.rb:35:in `each'
    from /Users/ps032791/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@record/gems/libv8-3.11.8.17/ext/libv8/location.rb:35:in `verify_installation!'
    from /Users/ps032791/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@record/gems/libv8-3.11.8.17/ext/libv8/location.rb:26:in `install!'
    from extconf.rb:7:in `<main>'
GYP_GENERATORS=make \
    build/gyp/gyp --generator-output="out" build/all.gyp \
                  -Ibuild/standalone.gypi --depth=. \
                  -Dv8_target_arch=x64 \
                  -S.x64  -Dv8_can_use_vfp_instructions=true
  CXX(target) /Users/ps032791/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@record/gems/libv8-3.11.8.17/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/allocation.o
  CXX(target) /Users/ps032791/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@record/gems/libv8-3.11.8.17/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/atomicops_internals_x86_gcc.o
  CXX(target) /Users/ps032791/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@record/gems/libv8-3.11.8.17/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/bignum.o
  CXX(target) /Users/ps032791/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@record/gems/libv8-3.11.8.17/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/bignum-dtoa.o
  CXX(target) /Users/ps032791/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@record/gems/libv8-3.11.8.17/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/cached-powers.o

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/ps032791/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@record/gems/libv8-3.11.8.17 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/ps032791/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@record/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/2.2.0-static/libv8-3.11.8.17/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing libv8 (3.11.8.17), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install libv8 -v '3.11.8.17'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Also `gem install libv8 -v '3.11.8.17'` fails on the same error.

Is there anyone who is getting a similar error? Could you please guide me on how to fix this??

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$ brew install v8
```

And then:
`$ gem install libv8 -v '3.16.14.3' -- --with-system-v8`
Then Bundle install.
Good luck.

Comment: Both the commands suceeded. But running `bundle install` again, gave the same old error.

Comment: That's weird, if both commands succeeded it should be OK, sorry for that, it worked for me.

Comment: @user3438489 make sure to specify the correct version number as seen in your stack trace error.